# Ruby On Rails I18n - Localization of errors.full_messages works on One Server But Not Another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling, localization, internationalization, message

I am using Ruby On Rails 3.2.13 Ruby 1.9.3.

I have the following code that I am using to display the messages Rails provides when validation is being done within a Model:

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="alert alert-error">
      <%=t :the_form_contains %> <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "#{t :error_text}") %>.
      <ul>
        <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
          <li>* <%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I also have some customized text in my yaml files.  Here is an example of how the messages appear on one server:

```
Le Formulaire contient 20 erreurs.
* Mot de passe doit être rempli(e)
* Prénom doit être rempli(e)
* Prénom est trop court (au moins 3 caractères)
* Prénom n'est pas valide
```

Here is how the messages appear on the other server:

```
Le Formulaire contient 20 erreurs.
* Mot de passe can't be blank
* Prénom can't be blank
* Prénom is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
* Prénom is invalid
```

Only the portions of the messages that I entered in the yaml files display properly.  The ones that Rails would translate only work on one server.

I read the Rails Guide for I18n here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html but did not see anything in config or anywhere else that I needed to do to get these working. As I stated it works fine on one server but not the other one.

If I did something on my development server that I did not do on my production server I do not remember what I did.  I have checked config/application.rb and config/environment.rb on both servers and they are the same.  Maybe there is something I need to initialize somewhere on my production server.  If an answer is found it may also solve the problem that I asked about in [Ruby on Rails I18n - Localization of Dates Works In localhost but Not In Production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17913851/ruby-on-rails-3-2-13-ruby-1-9-3-localization-of-dates-works-in-localhost-but-n).

Any help would be appreciated.  I will continue my research to see if I can find anything about this.  So far I have found nothing.

UPDATE: 7/29/2013 12:47 pm CDT - The only other difference that I can see between the two servers is that the development server is running ruby 1.9.3p327 and the production server is running ruby 1.9.3p362.  However I cannot believe that could be causing my problem but it is a difference that I feel I should note.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find any other questions or comments relating to this.  I decided to copy the fr.yml hashes for the rails-i18n gem.  I did not have to do this on my development server to get the error messages to translate into French.  As I stated it was working fine without them.  When I deployed the new yaml file in production all my clauses are in French.  I guess there is a needle in a haystack type of bug somewhere in the i18n process.  At least the Rails translations for error messages are working now.